# Trying to create a shared access policy for Azure event hub results in "Partition cannot be changed for EventHub."

Tags: azure-eventhub

I've created an Azure event hub and now I'm trying to add a "Listen" and a "Send" shared access policy. When I attempt to save them I get the following error:

```
SubCode=40000. PartitionCount cannot be changed for EventHub.
```

I'm not changing the "Partition Count", so I have not idea why I'm getting this error. Any suggestions on how to get around this problem?

Comment: Did u try creating Shared Access Policy from Azure Portal?

Answer (score 1):

I tried a similar thing with a template to update an existing Event Hub with additional consumer groups. My original template did not specify a "partitionCount" as part of the properties but when I added it the deployment worked.